# Integral over Gaussian function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request, definite-integrals

What is the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \exp(-a^2 (x-y)^2)) \, d x
$$
According to mathematica it equals
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (\text{erf}(a y)+\text{erf}(a(1- y)))}{2 a}
$$

But how can this be proven? This must have been done somewhere, can you give me a reference? Thanks!

Comment: this follows directly from the definition of the error function found 100's of times on the net...

Comment: here you can find something about this integral http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf

Comment: @Dr. Trollhard Graubner this link is remarkably useless

Comment: why is this useless?

Comment: @Trollhard because it is only loosely (at best) related to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change variables to $u = a(x-y)$ and then use the [definition of the error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html). You will need to split up the integral and use the evenness of the the new integrand.